# Remove the blank page in the print preview when using setTimeout to display the image

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem with print preview in Chrome. I want to print with images inside, but not show. So, I use setTimeout to display the image. The image successfully shows up, but the problem is when using setTimeout there is a blank page at last.

When not using setTimeout, there is no blank page. But the picture does not show.

So how do I get the blank page deleted?

[image]

My code:

```
function printDiv(divId) {
    var panel = document.getElementById(divId);
    var myWindow = window.open('', '', 'width=1200,height=790');    

    myWindow.document.write('<html><head><title>Print</title>');
    myWindow.document.write('<base href="' + location.origin + location.pathname + '">');
    myWindow.document.write('<link media="print" href="' + assets_url + 'css/lib/cetak.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">');
    myWindow.document.write('</head><body>'); 
    myWindow.document.write(panel.innerHTML); 
    myWindow.document.write('</body></html>');

    myWindow.document.close();
    myWindow.moveTo(0, 0);
    myWindow.resizeTo(screen.width, screen.height);

    setTimeout(function(){
        myWindow.focus();
        myWindow.print();
        myWindow.close();       
    },100);    

    return true;
}
```

Comment: I think your content exceeds the first page when image is there. Reduce the size and try again

Comment: or, in other words, it has nothing to do with `setTimeout` more likely to do with the size of the content after the image is inserted

Comment: @SankarRaj @Jaromanda I've resized, but still not change. There is still a blank page. Well, when I delete the image and keep using `setTimeout`, the empty page still exists.

Comment: @JaromandaX No. there is use for `setTimeout` in print function. If you have rich content to print in chrome browser, you should put some delay to open print dialog. otherwise the blank page will be shown because the print dialog has been triggered before the elements get rendered. I don't know, this is right or not. but used to do this way.

Comment: I didn't say there is no **use** for setTimeout, I **agreed** with your comment (and expanded on it) that the problem is with the resulting page, i.e. that the setTimeout is **not** the cause the issue

Comment: However, it seems that the setTimeout actually **is** somehow responsible, if the OP's comment is to be believed!!!

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the use of incorrect CSS class in document.write.

Change the CSS to appropriate Bootstrap related CSS and it will work.

This is not related to setTimeout function, it seems to work by removing the setTimeout but the data is not rendered in bootstrap. By changing the CSS class to correct Bootstrap CSS it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below line to remove only URL from print view

```
newWin = window.open("https://asdasdasd");
```

Sample:

```
var upper = document.getElementById("upper");
newWin = window.open("https://asdasdasd");
newWin.document.write(upper.outerHTML);
setTimeout(function () {
   newWin.print();
   newWin.close();
}, 400);
```